# In Julia, How can I column-normalize a sparse matrix?

Tags: matrix, normalization, sparse-matrix, julia

If I have constructed a sparse matrix using the sparse(i, j, k) constructor, how can I then normalize the columns of the matrix (so that each column sums to 1)? I cannot efficiently normalize the entries before I create the matrix, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be a broadcasting division by the sum of the columns:

```
julia> A = sprand(4,5,.5)
       A./sum(A,1)
4x5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0        0.0989976  0.0        0.0       0.0795486
 0.420754   0.458653   0.0986313  0.0       0.0
 0.0785525  0.442349   0.0        0.856136  0.920451
 0.500693   0.0        0.901369   0.143864  0.0
```

… but it looks like that hasn't been optimized for sparse matrices yet, and falls back to a full matrix.  So a simple loop to iterate over the columns does the trick:

```
julia> for (col,s) in enumerate(sum(A,1))
         s == 0 && continue # What does a "normalized" column with a sum of zero look like?
         A[:,col] = A[:,col]/s
       end
       A
4x5 sparse matrix with 12 Float64 entries:
    [2, 1]  =  0.420754
    [3, 1]  =  0.0785525
    [4, 1]  =  0.500693
    [1, 2]  =  0.0989976
    [2, 2]  =  0.458653
    [3, 2]  =  0.442349
    [2, 3]  =  0.0986313
    [4, 3]  =  0.901369
    [3, 4]  =  0.856136
    [4, 4]  =  0.143864
    [1, 5]  =  0.0795486
    [3, 5]  =  0.920451

julia> sum(A,1)
1x5 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

This works entirely within sparse matrices and is done in-place (although it is still allocating new sparse matrices for each column slice).

Answer (score 4):

Given a Matrix A (does not matter whether or not it is sparse) normalize by any dimension

```
 A ./ sum(A,1) or  A ./ sum(A,2)
```

to show that it works:

```
A = sprand(10,10,0.3)   
println(sum(A,1))
println(A ./ sum(A,1))
```

only caveat

```
A[1,:] = 0
println(A ./ sum(A,1))
```

as you can see the column 1 now only contains NaNs because we divide by zero. Also we end up  with a Matrix and not a sparse Matrix.

On the other hand one can quickly come up with an efficient specialized solution for your problem.

```
function normalize_columns(A :: SparseMatrixCSC)
          sums = sum(A,1)
          I,J,V = findnz(A)
          for idx in 1:length(V)
            V[idx] /= sums[J[idx]]
          end
          sparse(I,J,V)
end
```

@Matt B came up with a very similar answer while I was typing this up :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that sparse matrices in Julia are in compressed column form. So you can access the data directly:

```
for col = 1 : size(A, 2)
  i = A.colptr[col]
  k = A.colptr[col+1] - 1
  n = i <= k ? norm(A.nzval[i:k]) : 0.0  # or whatever you like
  n > 0.0 && (A.nzval[i:k] ./= n)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# get the column sums of A
S = vec(sum(A,1))

# get the nonzero entries in A. ei is row index, ej is col index, ev is the value in A
ei,ej,ev = findnz(A)

# get the number or rows and columns in A
m,n = size(A)

# create a new normalized matrix. For each nonzero index (ei,ej), its new value will be
# the old value divided by the sum of that column, which can be obtained by S[ej]
A_normalized = sparse(ei,ej,ev./S[ej],m,n)
```

Comment: For future reference, giving a bit of explanation behind your answer is a good thing. In this case, I don't understand what ei,ej,ev are used for - are they meant to be bi.bj.bv?

Answer (score 0):

the following gives what you want:
A = sprand(4,5,0.5)
B = A./sparse(sum(A,1))

The problem is that sum(A,1)  gives a  1x5 dense array so combining with the sparse matrix A through the ./ operator gives a dense array. So you need to force it to be of sparse type. Or you can type 
sparse(A ./ sum(A,1)).